# Angular arrangements of movie clips in action script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

i want to create a speed test application in action script 3.The speed meter that am planning is like an analog one.How could i arrange those.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what exactly you want, but I assume you're asking how to create a speed meter with an analog dial.

I will describe how to create this kind of meter http://bit.ly/pSOxnv - but can easily adapt to others.

You'll have two MovieClips:

- the **background** of the meter (nothing special here), just keep it on the bottom
- the **indicator** - basically just a fancy line. You will want to position this in the exact position on top of the background, and then adjust the transformation center to be exactly where the axis should be (our center of rotation) - http://bit.ly/pP1AgL .

After that, you will need to write some code to position the indicator to the correct value:

```
function updateDial(value: Number, max: Number) {
    var maxAngle: Number = 45; // adjust this angle to reach the maximum

    var u:Number = (value / max) * maxAngle;  // compute the angle

    indicator_mc.rotation = u;  // apply the rotation
}
```

If you want to manage the center point in actionscript too, then things will get more complicated, you will have to apply a Transformation Matrix to `mc.transform.matrix`. Read more about it here: http://bit.ly/oBcKOj

Comment: var myobjectcount:uint = 9;

for (var i = 0; i < myobjectcount; i++)
{
   var myobject:Myobject = new Myobject();
   addChild (myobject);

   var radius:Number = 150;
   var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;
   var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;

   myobject.angle = i *  ((Math.PI * 1) / (myobjectcount - 1));
   myobject.x = Math.cos(myobject.angle) * radius + centerX;
   myobject.y = Math.sin(myobject.angle) * radius + centerY;
}